# C++ correct way to move classes

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have classes who handle (Vulkan) ressources, lets call them
`VulkanInstance` and `VulkanDevice`.
My `Master` class owns both of these

```
class Master {
    VulkanInstance instance_;
    VulkanDevice device_;
    reset();
}
```

in my `reset` function i want to delete the current `instance` and `device` and create a new one.
I thought of the following conditions:

1. `device_` must be destroyed before `instace_` can be destroyed, because `device_` depends on `instance_`
2. `instance_` must be created before `device_` can be created
3. `device_` and `instance_` can't be copied, however they can be constructed, move contructed and move assigned
4. i want to create a new `VulkanInstance` and `VulkanDevice` before deleting the old `instance_` and `device_`. So that when i get errors during construction of the new elements i still have the old valid classes left.

My question is: How should i design the `reset` function. Can it be realised without using `pointers` / `std::unique_ptr` to `VulkanInstance` or `VulkanDevice`.

I though about something like this

```
 // PSEUDO CODE
 Master::reset() {
     VulkanInstance new_instance {};
     VulkanDevice new_device {};
     device_ = new_device; //use move here and destruct old device_ Dont use copy constructor
     instance_ = new_instance; //use move here and destruct old device_ Dont use copy constructor
 }
```

Comment: Why not use your assignment operator and use `reset() { *this = Master{}; }`?

Comment: `device_ = std::move(new_device);` if you want to move.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are move semantics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics)

Comment: Make sure to read their [supplementary answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics/11540204#11540204) to understand `std::move` itself.